# Gmail / Outlook/ Imap issues

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I was pretty content with Win7 so I stayed on it, using Outlook 2007 to bring my Gmail messages into Outlook using POP3 where rules would sort them into various folders.  I could also go to gmail.com to see my messages, or check them on my phone with the Gmail app.  Life was good.

Now Gmail doesn't allow POP3 connections like before, so I've upgraded to Win10/Outlook 2019 and I've set up my Gmail account using Imap.  Problem is that it has carried all the mail messages from the past into Outlook and removed them from the Gmail server.  They are no longer there if I go to gmail.com, or if I check the app on my phone.  I get that I likely won't be able to send the messages back, but what do I change so that future incoming messages can be viewed on gmail.com etc. after Outlook picks them up?

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, When you use IMAP, you can read your Gmail messages on multiple devices, and messages are synced in real time. Comparing these configuration steps in the [blog](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en#zippy=%2Cstep-check-that-imap-is-turned-on%2Cstep-change-smtp-other-settings-in-your-email-client) and make sure your configuration is right.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the rules were moving the messages to folder outside the Imap account.  Moved it all back, changed the rules, and all is good.